# Time-efficient manipulation (zeroing) of expression

Tags: matrix, expression-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have huge matrices in the form of

```
mtx1 = {{24+24 FF[6,9] GG[5,10]+24 FF[7,8] GG[5,10]+24 FF[5,10] GG[6,9]+24 FF[6,9] GG[6,9]+24 FF[7,8] GG[6,9]+24 FF[5,10] GG[7,8]+24 FF[6,9] GG[7,8]+24 FF[7,8] GG[7,8],24+24 FF[5,10] GG[5,10]+24 FF[6,9] GG[5,10]+24 FF[7,8] GG[5,10]+24 FF[6,9] GG[6,9]+24 FF[7,8] GG[6,9]+24 FF[5,10] GG[7,8]+24 FF[6,9] GG[7,8]+24 FF[7,8] GG[7,8],24+24 FF[5,10] GG[5,10]+24 FF[6,9] GG[5,10]+24 FF[7,8] GG[5,10]+24 FF[5,10] GG[6,9]+24 FF[6,9] GG[6,9]+24 FF[7,8] GG[6,9]+24 FF[6,9] GG[7,8]+24 FF[7,8] GG[7,8]},{24+24 FF[5,10] GG[5,10]+24 FF[7,8] GG[5,10]+24 FF[5,10] GG[6,9]+24 FF[6,9] GG[6,9]+24 FF[7,8] GG[6,9]+24 FF[5,10] GG[7,8]+24 FF[6,9] GG[7,8]+24 FF[7,8] GG[7,8],24+24 FF[5,10] GG[5,10]+24 FF[6,9] GG[5,10]+24 FF[7,8] GG[5,10]+24 FF[5,10] GG[6,9]+24 FF[7,8] GG[6,9]+24 FF[5,10] GG[7,8]+24 FF[6,9] GG[7,8]+24 FF[7,8] GG[7,8],24+24 FF[5,10] GG[5,10]+24 FF[6,9] GG[5,10]+24 FF[7,8] GG[5,10]+24 FF[5,10] GG[6,9]+24 FF[6,9] GG[6,9]+24 FF[7,8] GG[6,9]+24 FF[5,10] GG[7,8]+24 FF[7,8] GG[7,8]},{24+24 FF[5,10] GG[5,10]+24 FF[6,9] GG[5,10]+24 FF[5,10] GG[6,9]+24 FF[6,9] GG[6,9]+24 FF[7,8] GG[6,9]+24 FF[5,10] GG[7,8]+24 FF[6,9] GG[7,8]+24 FF[7,8] GG[7,8],24+24 FF[5,10] GG[5,10]+24 FF[6,9] GG[5,10]+24 FF[7,8] GG[5,10]+24 FF[5,10] GG[6,9]+24 FF[6,9] GG[6,9]+24 FF[5,10] GG[7,8]+24 FF[6,9] GG[7,8]+24 FF[7,8] GG[7,8],24+24 FF[5,10] GG[5,10]+24 FF[6,9] GG[5,10]+24 FF[7,8] GG[5,10]+24 FF[5,10] GG[6,9]+24 FF[6,9] GG[6,9]+24 FF[7,8] GG[6,9]+24 FF[5,10] GG[7,8]+24 FF[6,9] GG[7,8]}};
```

but the matrices I use are much bigger. Now I want to get rid of each term that contains `FF[___]` or `GG[___]`. Both always come together, therefore I used

```
mtx2 = mtx1 /. FF[___] -> 0; 
(* mtx2={{24, 24, 24}, {24, 24, 24}, {24, 24, 24}} *)
```

and got the desired result in mtx2. Unfortunatly it turns out that this zeroing is extremly time-consuming. For my huge matrices, it takes on the order of 100 seconds.

**Question:**

Is there a more time-efficient way to zero all `FF[___]`-terms in `mtx1`?

**Comparison:**

I compare several approaches, for a big 3 big test-matrix. The approaches also include the construction of the matrix.

*my original approach*

- {174.8417751, 65.4913582, 25.3878123} seconds

*Coefficient-Creation of Matrix*

- {134.4920621, 51.4260521sec, 19.6079772} seconds

*belisarius' Block-evaluation methode*

- {82.3675688, 31.5639078, 12.3822025} seconds

*eldo's Join/Partition*

- {77.8615328, 29.0973367, 11.2742769} seconds

*kguler's Block-evaluation*

- {75.8906436, 29.1315892, 11.6544345} seconds

*Mr.Wizard's mtx1[[All, All, 1]]*

- {75.5589726, 29.0378220, 11.9491954} seconds

**Edit**

The full problem, including the matrix-creation is posted here: 
[Time-efficient creation of matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57241/time-efficient-creation-of-matrix)

Comment: Why not a scope-aware redefinition `FF[x__]:=0`?

Comment: Thought about that aswell. I am using FF[__] as undefined parameters, which with I continue calculating later. it should stay undefined. But maybe an intermediate definition and evaluation?

Comment: `Block[{FF}, FF[__] = 0; a = mtx1]`

Comment: Wow, even the matrix-construction is slower, your Block-evaluation outperforms my approach alot, see above. To have a fair comparison, i should also post the matrix construction method - for this i need some time.

Comment: ... or `a = Block[{F = 0 &}, mtx1]`

Comment: .. `a = Block[{Times = 0 &}, mtx1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example you gave `FF[___]` and `GG[___]` are the only non-number terms, therefore by polynomial sort order you could use simply:

```
mtx1[[All, All, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{24, 24, 24}, {24, 24, 24}, {24, 24, 24}}
> ```

I shall now look at your newer question where I anticipate a more representative example.

Comment: LOL, you don't mind that I leave my answer for comparison purposes?

Comment: @eldo I didn't notice you were doing the same thing but verbosely.  I found the question odd so I did no more than glance at your answer before posting.  For some reason I thought you were doing something with `Position` but I misread.

Comment: See above, your approach seems to be the fastest one. Nice solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Given the structure of your SQUARE example matrix this should be fast:

```
dim = First @ Dimensions @ mtx1
```

> 3

```
tup = Join [#, {1}] & /@ Tuples[Range@dim, 2]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 1},
>   {3,1, 1}, {3, 2, 1}, {3, 3, 1}}

```
Partition[mtx1[[#1, #2, #3]] & @@@ tup, dim]
```

> {{24, 24, 24}, {24, 24, 24}, {24, 24, 24}}

Oneliner:

```
With[{dim = First@Dimensions@mtx1}, 
 Partition[mtx1[[#1, #2, #3]] & @@@ #, dim] &[
  Join [#, {1}] & /@ Tuples[Range@dim, 2]]]
```

Comment: This works very fast, thanks. I will write the compareing results down later. I posted the full problem (construction of a matrix, see above), for which this is a subproblem. Maybe you also have a solution for that? Thanks!!