# Time-efficient creation of matrix

Tags: matrix, expression-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have expressions like

```
xx1=FF[1, 1] GG[1, 1] + FF[1, 1] GG[2, 2] + FF[2, 2] GG[2, 2]
xx2=2*FF[1, 2] GG[1, 1] + FF[1, 1] GG[1, 2] + FF[2, 2] GG[2, 2]
```

and I want to transform it to special matrices

```
CreateMatrix[xx1] (* {{1, 1}, {0, 1}} *)
CreateMatrix[xx2] (* {{0, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}} *)
```

The logic of `CreateMatrix` is that we construct a grid like this (here using elements from `xx1`):

```
{{FF[1, 1] GG[1, 1], FF[1, 1] GG[2, 2]}, 
 {FF[2, 2] GG[1, 1], FF[2, 2] GG[2, 2]}}
```

and if say `FF[1,1] GG[1,1]` exists in the expression then its coefficient takes the place of `F[1,1], GG[1,1]` in the grid. Elements that exist in the grid but not in the expression are taken to be zero.

My code works, but is slow (it runs a double-for-loop to fill the matrix):

```
CreateMatrix[state_] := (
  ElementsFF = Union[Cases[state, _FF, {0, Infinity}]];
  ElementsGG = Union[Cases[state, _GG, {0, Infinity}]];
  MatrixSize = Length[ElementsFF];
  startTime = AbsoluteTime[];
  If[MatrixSize > 0,
   dM = IdentityMatrix[MatrixSize];
   For[k = 1, k <= MatrixSize, k++,
    For[l = 1, l <= MatrixSize, l++,
      dM[[k, l]] = state /. {ElementsFF[[k]]*ElementsGG[[l]] -> 1};
      ];
    ];
   Block[{FF}, FF[__] = 0; dM = dM];
   Print["After MatrixConstr: " <> ToString[AbsoluteTime[] - startTime]]; 
   startTime = AbsoluteTime[];,
   dM = 0;
   ];
  Return[dM];
  )

xx1= FF[1, 1] GG[1, 1] + FF[1, 1] GG[2, 2] + FF[2, 2] GG[2, 2]
CreateMatrix[xx1]
```

A small part of the code is already optimized from [an earlier partial question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57232/time-efficient-manipulation-zeroing-of-expression).

> Can you create a faster algorithm for the given problem?

**Comparison**

I test with three huge matrices (those which I need later).

*My original approach*

- {136.7564571, 51.4342097, 20.0780016} seconds

*kguler's solution*

- {123.7996434, 46.8804843, 19.1074500} seconds

*Mr.Wizard's solution1*

- {123.3144573, 47.5587309, 18.2832670} seconds

*Mr.Wizard's solution2*

- {0.0510345, 0.0315209, 0.0255171} seconds (!!!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is like a [Rube Goldberg machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine)!  Try this instead:

```
fn[state_] :=
 Outer[Coefficient[state, #*#2] &, ##] & @@
  (Union @ Cases[state, #, -2] & /@ {_FF, _GG})
```

Test:

```
test = 7 FF[1, 1] GG[1, 1] + 2 FF[1, 1] GG[2, 2] + 4 FF[2, 2] GG[2, 2] + 11 FF[2, 1] GG[2, 4];

fn[test] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  7 & 2 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 11 \\
>  0 & 4 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Also look at [`CoefficientArrays`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CoefficientArrays.html):

```
CoefficientArrays[test, Sort @ Variables @ test][[3]] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 7 & 2 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 11 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

---

If it is to be assumed that all symbolic coefficients that appear are to be treated like `_FF` and `_GG` above a general method may be written using `CoefficientArrays` as follows:

```
fn2[state_] :=
 With[{sa = CoefficientArrays[state, Sort @ Variables @ state][[3]]},
  Normal @ sa[[##]] & @@ (Min@# ;; Max@# &) /@ (sa @ "NonzeroPositions"\[Transpose])
 ]
```

This is superior to using `Coefficient` as the `state` expression is not rescanned repeatedly, leading to significantly better performance.  As a rather extreme example:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

test2 = Sum[RandomInteger[999] FF[i] GG[j], {i, 30}, {j, 30}];

(r1 = fn[test2])  // AccurateTiming
(r2 = fn2[test2]) // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 1.613092
>
> 0.00180972
> ```

```
r1 === r2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

One more update to address the new format you describe in a comment.

```
fn3[state_] :=
 MapThread[{#, #2} -> #3 &,
   MapAt[
     ArrayComponents[#, 1] &,
     Cases[state, C_*_[a_, b_, c_, d_] :> {{a, b}, {c, d}, C}]\[Transpose],
     ;; 2
   ]
 ] // SparseArray
```

Now:

```
t2 = test /. FF[a_, b_] GG[c_, d_] :> JJ[a, b, c, d]
```

> ```
> 7 JJ[1, 1, 1, 1] + 2 JJ[1, 1, 2, 2] + 11 JJ[2, 1, 2, 4] + 4 JJ[2, 2, 2, 2]
> ```

```
fn3[t2] // MatrixForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  7 & 2 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 11 \\
>  0 & 4 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: wow, the second solution is more than 2600times faster than my approach :-o. Awesome!

Comment: I tried to use your code, but replaced the input FF[a, b] GG[c, d] by JJ[a,b,c,d]. I was unable to change it. Could you please give a hint? Thx!

Comment: @NicoDean I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean.  Would you please append a complete example of the input and output that you expect for this new case?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Imagine the input of `fn2` is `xx1=JJ[1, 1, 1, 1] + JJ[1, 1, 2, 2] + JJ[2, 2, 2, 2]`. How would I change `fn2` to get the same results as before with `fn2[JJ[1, 1, 1, 1] + JJ[1, 1, 2, 2] + JJ[2, 2, 2, 2]]`? (obviously I could add the following line: `xx1/.{JJ[a_,b_,c_,d_] -> FF[a,b]*GG[c,d]}`. But thats an ugly workaround)

Comment: @NicoDean Assuming I understand now your "ugly workaround" seems like a perfectly good approach.  However I'll add another one to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I thought its straight forward to generalise your fn2-approach, but it seems like you use this very special property of `state`. Thanks again!

Comment: @Nico I can only follow the examples that you give me.  I suggest converting any other formats you encounter using your "ugly workaround" and then using `fn2` but I also wanted to show you how this might be done without `CoefficientArrays`.  I think the original question has been well answered now so if you have further extensions please post a new Question.

Answer (score 3):

A variation on @MrW's answer using a combination of `Outer`, `Coefficient`, `Variables` and `GatherBy`:

```
func = Function[{state}, 
   Coefficient[state, #] &@
    Outer[Times, ## & @@ (Sort /@ GatherBy[Variables[state], Head])]];
```

Test:

```
xx1 = FF[1, 1] GG[1, 1] + FF[1, 1] GG[2, 2] + FF[2, 2] GG[2, 2];
xx2 = 2*FF[1, 2] GG[1, 1] + FF[1, 1] GG[1, 2] + FF[2, 2] GG[2, 2];
test = 7 FF[1, 1] GG[1, 1] + 2 FF[1, 1] GG[2, 2] + 
   4 FF[2, 2] GG[2, 2] + 11 FF[2, 1] GG[2, 4];
test2 = 7 FF[3, 1] GG[1, 1] HH[1, 1] + 2 FF[3, 1] GG[2, 2] HH[1, 2] + 
  4 FF[2, 2] GG[2, 2] + 11 FF[2, 1] GG[2, 4] HH[1, 3]

func[xx1]
(* {{1, 1}, {0, 1}} *)
func[xx2]
(* {{0, 1, 0}, {2, 0, 0},{0, 0, 1}} *)
func[test]
(* {{7, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 11}, {0, 4, 0}} *)
func[test2]
(*{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0 ,0, 11}},
   {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}},
   {{7, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}}*)
```

Comment: +1 for making it general. I had another answer using pattern matching but yours and @Mr.Wizard's answers were clearly superior than mine.

Comment: @kguler nice, this generalization.

Comment: Please see the update to my answer.